Postfix additional character for + sub-addressing
For many years already our mailservers have supported the plus + character in the local-part of an e-mail address as a separator for sub-addressing & RFC 5233 which allows our users create unlimited "aliases" and "unique e-mail addresses" without further intervention and set-up serverside. That is nice and easy for our users and avoids the complications associated with maintaining "real" aliases.
For example: my mailbox is hbruijn@example.com but I can sign up here with hbruijn+ServerFault@example.com  and I will receive the emails ServerFault sends directly in my Inbox.
I think this setup was carried forward from when the company was still using sendmail and Postfix supports this with the setting:
 recipient_delimiter = + 

The problem
Many developers create sign-up forms with input validation and their broken cargo-cult RegEx or input validation library rejects valid e-mail addresses that contain a + in the local-user recipient.
This problem appears to be getting more prevalent rather than better.
How can I improve our sub-addressing to work around those broken forms?
Although Postfix allows any arbitrary character as the recipient_delimiter completely changing  to a different character, that isn't rejected as often, would be a breaking change and is not an option.
The manual suggests that Postfix can support multiple characters concurrently:
https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

# Handle both Postfix and qmail extensions (Postfix 2.11 and later).
recipient_delimiter = +-


Questions:

What would the "best" character to use as an additional delimiter?
One that isn't as frequently rejected by mail forms...
The suggested hyphen -, a percent
%, for example the RFC 5233 hash # or something else entirely that doesn't conflict with our account/mailbox naming scheme?

The + plus is supported pretty well by other software and/or mail providers, but how unique is Postfix in supporting multiple custom delimiters?
Would be we forever tied to Postfix when we change the
recipient_delimiter to include another character?



Exim supports this and its relatively simple to implement, sendmail, of course, can handle it but I suspect you'd need to write your own m4 macro (does anyone still configure sendmail.cf directly?). It's sad that email administrators spend so much time working around other people's re-invention of the protocols.

("this" being custom delimiters)

With the knowledge that exim also supports this, I found a recipe here for implementing the + , -and _  as delimiters in exim + dovercot  that uses exim settings local_part_suffix = +* : -* : _* and local_part_suffix_optional.  So we won't be locked in to using Postfix if we would make the change to allow multiple delimiters.

Have you considered per user subdomains? ServerFault@hbruijn.example.com -> hbruijn+ServerFault@example.com and wildcard DNS records.

That would be a breaking change and I have the impression that per user subdomains are typically configured either with a catch-all (which based on past experience with a catch-all on my personal domain means a lot more spam) or still require explicit setup of each alias. I can see a use-case and the advantage which is  of course that each user can have whatever aliases they might want rather a first-come , first-serve landgrab  ; I can get ServerFault@hbruijn.example.com and Alice can get her own ServerFault@alice.example.com
